# Sleep functionality is not working in Interrupt service routine in PIC controller

Tags: sleep, mplab, isr

I am using Pic controller (PIC16F15325) in simulaotor window, and I am facing one issue regarding Sleep functionality. I have declared Pin "RA2" as external interrupt pin (High to low transition) and I am changing forcefully value of "RA2" from 1 to 0, from variable window. After doing that "ISR" is never got called.
All the Initialization code i have used, it is generated from MPLAB code configurator only. Can anyone tell me the reason, why interrupt is not generated after triggering the value.

I am putting my sample code here, which i used for testing:

```
/* code */
SYSTEM_Initialize();

INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();

INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();

while (1)
{
        if(PORTAbits.RA2 == 1)
        {
            SLEEP();
            __nop();


        }
        else
        {
            PORTCbits.RC3 = 1;
            PORTCbits.RC4 = 1;

        }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured `RA2`as digital and as ìnput?

Comment: where is `main`?

Comment: Yes, I configured RA2 as digital and input and the code whatever i have provided this is only the "main".

Comment: so show your complete code